# Find value in array then return true with Angular forEach

Tags: javascript, angularjs, foreach

I'm learning JavaScript and AngularJS.

What's the difference between this code?

```
function isInArrayNgForeach(field, arr) {
    angular.forEach(arr, function(value, key) {
        if(field == value)
            return true;
    });
    return false;
} // This returns always false

function isInArrayJavaScript(field, arr) {
    for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if(field == arr[i])
            return true;
    }
    return false;
} // This works fine

function isInArray() {
    var testArr = ['stack', 'over', 'flow'];
    console.log(isInArrayNgForeach('stack', testArr)); // return false
    console.log(isInArrayJavaScript('stack', testArr)); // return true
}
```

My question is: why **isInArrayNgForeach** always return *false*?  I assume that because there is a function inside of the function, but I'm not sure why.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The first option is different because `return true;` returns from the function which is passed as parameter to `forEach` function not from the outer function `isInArrayNgForeach` and that's why the last line `return false;` gets called always when the forEach finishes. Which makes the function return false always.

If you change the code like this, tt will return expected result:

```
function isInArrayNgForeach(field, arr) {
    var result = false;

    angular.forEach(arr, function(value, key) {
        if(field == value)
            result = true;
    });

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for (the detail explanation && the example code)

Comment: after setting `result=true`, you should `return`, otherwise it'll iterate for every element even after a match.

Answer (score 5):

```
function isInArrayNgForeach(field, arr) {
    angular.forEach(arr, function(value, key) {
        if(field == value)
            return true; // You are returning the immediate function here not isInArrayNgForeach
   ...
```

To make it work as you intend it to

```
function isInArrayNgForeach(field, arr) {
    var result = false;
    angular.forEach(arr, function(value, key) {
        if(field == value)
            result = true;
    });
    return result;
} // This returns expected value
```

Answer (score 1):

In function `isInArrayNgForeach` you are returning `true` to the anonymous function given to `forEach`. It'll never go to `isInArrayNgForeach`. And at last you are saying `return false` which will be always returned.

It is like

```
function isInArrayNgForeach(field, arr) {
    //do something except return
    return false;
} // So it will always return false
```

If you want to achieve what you are doing in your second function, the javascript native `some` will help you.

```
function isInArrayNgForeach(field, arr) {
    return arr.some(function(element){return element==field});
    //it will check if any element is equal to field it will return true otherwise false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For primitives you could still just use array.indexOf...

```
var arr = ['foo', 'bar', 0, 22];
if (arr.indexOf('bar') > -1) {
    // 'bar' is in arr 
}
```