# AngularJS function returning at wrong point

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I have the following JavaScript function, which will loop through an array of 3 objects, each time meeting the condition of the if statement and returning true. Why does it not return after the first time it hits true and instead continues looping through the array? This does of course result in the function returning false because it hits that after the loop.

I have got around this issue just by creating a different variable and returning it at the end, but I am just curious why it is doing this?

```
this.CheckRoles = function (authLevel) {

    angular.forEach(currentUser.roles, function (role) {

        if(role >= authLevel)
        {
            //The user has the required permissions
            return true;
        }

    });

    return false;
}
```

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25061454/3894168) should solve your problem.

Comment: You could set a flag inside the forEach method instead of return and check the flag outside(after) the loop and return true/false based on your requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're returning from the callback you pass to `angular.forEach`, not from the `CheckRoles` function.

Just like the native `forEach` (and unlike jQuery's `each`), there's no clean way to stop the `angular.forEach` loop. You might throw an exception if you're OK with a dirty solution, or just use a standard loop:

```
this.CheckRoles = function (authLevel) {
    for (var i=0; i<currentUser.roles.length; i++) {
        var role = currentUser.roles[i];
        if (role >= authLevel) {
            //The user has the required permissions
            return true; // really return, don't iterate over other roles
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

If you still want to use `angular.forEach` (and thus iterate over the whole array), you have to ensure the value is passed:

```
this.CheckRoles = function (authLevel) {
    var ok = false;
    angular.forEach(currentUser.roles, function (role) {
        if(role >= authLevel) {
            //The user has the required permissions
            ok = true;
        }
    });
    return ok;
}
```

If you don't need to support IE8, there's a very clean and efficient solution using [some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some#Browser_compatibility):

```
this.CheckRoles = function (authLevel) {
    return currentUser.roles.some(function(role){
        return role >= authLevel;
    });
}
```

Comment: The second approach is the way I used to get around it. Thanks for the clear explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Because you are returning from forEach callback function NOT from the outer CheckRoles Function.

Answer (score 0):

The true return returns from the inner function and not the outer one. This is not a regular for each iteration loop, where return from the loop body will return from the function. The way to do what you intend to do is by setting a variable in the inner function and returning it from the outer one.